# Laravel method not allowed

Tags: php, laravel, routes, adminlte

I am getting a `MethodNotAllowedException` when trying to submit my form. Here are my routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {

    Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
    Route::get('user/destroyMe/{destroyMe}', ['as' => 'user.destroyMe', 'uses' => 'UserController@destroyMe']);
    Route::get('user/changeState/{id}', ['as' => 'user.changeState', 'uses' => 'UserController@changeState']);
});
```

And here is the form part with storing the new user:

```
<div class="position-center">
    <form role="form" id="tryitForm" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data"
          method="POST" action="{{route('user.store')}}">
        {!! Form::token() !!}
```

I've checked within `route:list` and I clearly have the `user.store` named route, and method on the route is `POST`. I can't figure out why am I getting the exception?

**EDIT**

I do have an AdminLTE for Laravel installed [Link](https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel), but I've overriden its routes. Needles to say that every other route works.

**EDIT 2**

I tried making a manual route:

```
Route::post('admin/user', 'UserController@store');
```

and posting it to the `url('admin/user')` but still the same result?

**EDIT 3**

Clearing the cache didn't help also.

**EDIT 4**

After further inspection, when hitting a random route which doesn't exist, I get an error header that `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`, but if I do any of the `POST` routes, I get `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.` (both errors trigger the same exception though).

Laravel log is empty

Comment: which route is user.store route i cant see?

Comment: and also i cant see the Route::post in you routes?

Comment: `Route:resource` is making all the default routes

Comment: so where is Route::post?

Comment: What version of Laravel?

Comment: @Araz `resource()` creates 7 routes, including `user.store`

Comment: 5.4.15 is the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an error causing all the trouble. Inside my form there was a line

```
<input name="_method" value="PUT" type="hidden">
```

It sneaked there by copy/pasting my `edit` code

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
 {!! Form::open( [ 'route' => 'user.store', 'method' => 'POST',  'files' => 'true' ] ) !!}
```

And do close it.

```
      //
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**Edit:**
How about doing it this way:

In `routes.php`

```
 Route::any('admin/user', 'UserController@form');
```

And in the `controller`:

```
 public function form(){
    print_r(Input::get()); die; #Hope that you are using Input.
 }
```

Comment: It's just another way to write it using package. Same result unfortunately

Comment: @Norgul Edited this with a new approach.

Comment: Here is the output `Array ( [_token] => GS8E6Jx9Xrs2B97qa8VmRquuCdTc259aecdrJdrd [name] => Tyler Clay [email] => tagi@yahoo.com [role_id] => 7 [equipment] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 ) [supervisor] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 ) [_method] => PUT [save] => Save )` so I guess it is hitting the route

Comment: But there must be something in my config confusing...because even if I comment out all routes, and use default AdminLTE routes, hitting `/logout` gets me back the same exception, so I ended up making a GET route for logout

Comment: Your method says `[_method] => PUT` instead of `POST`. That's strange.

Comment: I did have some trouble days ago with my dev environment because of the updates, so I ended up changing PHP version to 7.1. in `nginx/sites-available`. Maybe I should update the whole system and hope for the best. Btw I updated the post a bit